# N ot getting CA Siteminder SMSESSION Cookie in response

Tags: iis-7.5, single-sign-on, httphandler, siteminder, integrated-pipeline-mode

We are implementing CA Site minder on external server for single sign on.
We did all necessary configuration on our server as well as on policy server.

When I hit my URL request get interrupted by ISAPI Filter and Site Minder Replace it with Log in Page Then I put credentials and click log in.

This request goes to policy server and after authenticating site minder redirect me to original url that I hit early on but somehow i am not getting SMSESSION Cookie.

I check FRT log and found that cookie is there in Request Header which mean site minder able to generate and pass the cookie to request but not set in Response header So its getting removed from response.

I tried to find why its getting removed or response not setting SMSESSION Cookie but not able to find any reason.

I am using Integrated pipeline mode and the same setup is working fine with classic mode but since my application is MVC I can't use that and i have to use integrated mode.

Answer (score 1):

The SMSESSION cookie is not provided to the application from SiteMinder. It is initialized in the client browser after login and should be included when the authenticated request arrives back at your application.

I suggest monitoring the client side to ensure the SMSESSION is received after login and sent back out in the application request.

Comment: No i dont think it is initialize by client after login ca login page redirect to our requested url with forcred and SMTRY cookie and i return web agent generate and send SMSESSION Cookie.In my case agent generating the cookie but i am not getting it and need to find why?